# Getting the value from HTML into javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm not entirely certain if what I'm trying to do may be possible.
However,

```
<button class = "numbers" value=1>1</button>
all the way to 
<button class = "numbers" value=9>9</button>
```

For example, I have 1 all the way to 9, when one of these buttons were to be clicked, I want the values to be console logged. So, if I clicked the number 1 for example, it would just console log 1 as an int using the value of that specific button, without having to specify each button individually.

Thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: I don't think buttons really have a "value" attribute, but you could use `<input type='button' value='1' />`. You'll need to assign an event listener for the click event. I'd definitely  look for a JS tutorial for this.

Comment: @user1599011 The [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) element has a `value` attribute and property.

Comment: @user1599011 Ah, is setting a value on button, not a good practice? Should I use input type instead?

Comment: I was wrong; I don't use it and didn't realize it was valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation. Add one event listener to the container of the buttons, and on click, if the target (the innermost clicked element) was a button that matches `.numbers`, log the value.

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.numbers')) return;
  console.log(target.value);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class = "numbers" value=1>1</button>
  <button class = "numbers" value=9>9</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, this is what I originally thought to use event targets with a container. Thank you! :)

Comment: Ah, Event delegation and Event propagation. I'll read up on both of these again.